# When calling a service URL from SSRS, how do I set HTTP header values?

Tags: xml, rest, reporting-services, http-headers, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to call a REST web service from an SSRS report (XML data source).
By default, the service returns JSON, but if the "Accept" HTTP header is set to "application/xml", it will return XML.
I have tested this using Postman and with my web browser (Postman allows me to set the headers, and my browser sends application/xml by default).

How can I set this HTTP header in my XML data source so that SSRS also gets XML from the service?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to configure your endpoint in a way that you can call it like endpoint/xml and endpoint/json.

Comment: @Ross Bush - That would be easier, if I owned the endpoint or had access to the code. I do not.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm having problems with the exact same problem.

Comment: @BaBa Unfortunately, no. The only solutions I was able to find involved changing the service. You could change the service to accept the data format as a parameter, or to create a new controller that returned the desired format, or whatever else you can think of. But I was never able to find a way to get SSRS to set the appropriate header. As far as I can tell, this simply isn't supported.